# Application works in Tomcat but not in JBoss AS

Tags: tomcat, jboss, geronimo

I have written my application (webMathematica) for the Tomcat Webserver. Later on we tried to deploy the same application in Jboss, but it didn't work.

Here is the procedure that I followed to deploy the application in JBoss AS:

Following this [link](http://www.centerkey.com/jboss/) I was able to install JBoss AS, deploy and run the Hello World sample application successfully. But when I try to do the same thing with my own application (webMathematica), I can deploy it with success, but it does not runs.

I get the following error accessing `http://localhost:8080/webMathematica/` on my browser.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

 description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from    fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.wolfram.msp.MSPKernelRequest.releaseKernelAsync(MSPKernelRequest.java:190)
com.wolfram.msp.MSPServletRequestListener.requestDestroyed(MSPServletRequestListener.java:77)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Note: I've copied the application from Tomcat's webapps folder and wrapped it into a WAR file before deploying it in JBoss AS.

The same application worked fine when I deployed it in Geronimo Application Server.

Why won't my application work in the JBoss AS?

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace in http://snipplr.com/ and post the link here?

Comment: What is the version of JBoss AS you use?

Comment: Could you try with [JBoss EAP 6.1](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap)? If it still appears, feel free to [file a bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWEB).

Comment: Am using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I have downloaded and installed JBoss EAP 6.1, but still same error.

Comment: I have deployed my application in jboss 4.0.2 version which has tomcat 5.5.9 version and it is working well.
I think the jboss web(forked version of tomcat) is not suppport my application.
 
Can any one suggest me how can I make my application work with jboss-as 7.1.1.final version or tell me how can I replace jboss web(forked version of tomcat) with tomcat component in jboss-as 7.1.1.final